# Slider Extender Control in Ajax asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using Slider Extender for the very first time and i am not able to figure out why am i facing this problem, the problem is mentioned below :

I kept the slider extender, Script Manager and 2 text boxes(one for TargetControl and one for BoundControl), i have given all required values (i.e. Maximum, minimum, steps etc.)
now the slider should load on page load. Although the slider is loading on page load but the Bar of the slider is coming out of position. The same thing when i did with Orientation as Horizontal it worked properly but for Vertical orientation it is giving the above problem.
Please look into it.Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This problem is there in the Slidercontrol. Nothing can be done about it, i guess.